# Variáveis estáticas, privadas e finais

Tags: java, android

Tenho uma dúvida que vem me perturbando há muito tempo:

- Qual a vantagem de se criar uma variável estática e final (tanto privada, quanto pública)?
- Se eu tenho uma variável primitiva ou de classes simples (String por exemplo), elas possuem valores finais e são privadas. Elas deveriam ser estáticas?
- No caso anterior, qual o impacto de memória num dispositivo Android?

Até onde sei, criar variáveis de tipos que interajam com o contexto do aplicativo pode acontecer um vazamento de memória, por isso sei que isso é um "prática ruim". Porém, e quanto a variáveis mais simples?

*Obs: Instalei um plugin no Android Studio que me dizia para colocar final até em variáveis locais e que são argumento. Não entendi a real necessidade, e por isso não hesitei em perguntar aqui, para quem sabe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variáveis finais são apenas constantes, ou seja, não poderão receber novos valores.

Variáveis estáticas são variáveis da classe, ou seja, não dependem da criação de um objeto para serem usadas e todos os objetos dessa classe vão ter acesso ao valor desta variável.

Variável privada e pública são apenas restrições de acesso que você configura. Privada só o próprio objeto acessa e público qualquer um.

A combinação de definições acima vai depender da estratégia e lógica que você está implementando. Nunca ouvi falar que exista diferença de performance entre elas. Pelo menos nos treinamentos, mesmo os oficiais, que já fiz, nunca levantaram essa questão.

Variável de classe no lugar de primitiva (Integer no lugar de int, por ex) vieram para adicionar recursos que as primitivas não tem (ex: checar se é nulo). Tem menos performance, mas é tão insignificante que não vale a pena deixar de usar pensando nisso.

A parte do contexto que você citou não entendi.

As sugestões do Android Studio visam aumentar a eficiência do código. Por exemplo: se você cria uma variável que não muda de valor e nenhum outro método acessa, por que não criar ela como constante e local dentro do método que a utiliza?

Comment: A razão do compilador exigir que uma variável local seja `final` tem haver com o facto de ela ser usada em uma *inner class*. A questão do *Context* tem haver com a destruição/recreação das Activities. Se houver uma referência estática a uma Activity/Context quando ela for destruída/recreada ela não será colectada pelo Garbage Collector, originando um vazamento de memória.

Comment: Então, a questão do Context é isso mesmo. Porém, quanto a variável final, o plugin me sugestiona a usar final até nas variáveis que são argumentos em um construtor! Não utilizo elas em uma classe aninhada, apenas passo tais variáveis para as privadas da classe...

Comment: Isso tem haver, não só com o explicado no último parágrafo da resposta, mas também com a "boa prática" de que valores passados a construtor não devem ser alterados.

Comment: Sim, eu entendi. Mas achava que tinha a ver mais com segurança ou eficiência em memória

Comment: @GH_ A memória para uma variável *static* (variável da classe) só é alocada uma vez. Uma variável não *static* (variável da instância) é alocada por cada instância.

Comment: @ramaral, então a melhor prática, seria (caso a variável seja privada e estática apenas) anular seus valores assim que a activity fosse destruída? ou não tem nada a ver?
Caso a variável seja final, estática e privada, estaria basicamente apenas acumulando memória (caso exista mais activities)?
Confere?

Comment: Uma variável estática quer seja privada ou pública, final ou não, se inicializada, o seu valor(memória) é mantido durante a vida da aplicação. Uma variável não estática tem a sua ocupação de memória liberada quando não for mais referenciada e quando o Garbage Collector entender. Se tiver variáveis estáticas que referenciam Context(Activity é um Context) deve "anulá-las" antes da Activity ser destruída.